# Excel Sumif with formula in criteria

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I want to sum column c, when column A = "apple" and column c / column b > abs(1)

```
A                   B        C
Fuji Apple          2       $8
William Pear        1       $4
Pink Lady Apple     2       $1
Sundowner Apple     2       -$4
```

I tried the following formula and get answer is 0 but I expect it to pick up $8 (Fuji Apple) and -$4 (Sundowner Apple)

```
=SUMIFS(c:c,a:a, "*apple*",c:c, "ABS(c1/b1)>1")
```

Can you please advise what would be the correct formula to use?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if I understood correctly:

[image]

Col D does the absolute bit, otherwise I think you would be going to an array formula,...

Answer (score 0):

The following is a CSE formula.  This mean that when you enter the formula you press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you are done instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  Having said that, you do not want to use full column references like A:A as it will cause many unnecessarily calculations and slow down your computer or potentially crash it.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(SEARCH("Apple",$A$1:$A$4)>=1,0))*(ABS($C$1:$C$4/$B$1:$B$4)>1)*$C$1:$C$4)
```

OR

```
=SUM((IFERROR(SEARCH("Apple",$A$1:$A$4)>=1,0))*(ABS($C$1:$C$4/$B$1:$B$4)>1)*$C$1:$C$4)
```

Small caveat, cells in column C for the rows being looked at cannot be blank or equal to 0.  It will cause a divide by 0 error.